# Mapnik Stylesheet with URLs to assets?

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapnik

Example:

```
<PointSymbolizer transform="scale(0.5)" file="Traffic_Congestion_ORANGE_InMap.png" ignore-placement="true"/>
```

Here the **file** value seams only to be a local path (on the local filesystem)

Is there a way to specify the png via URL? A S3 URL for example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to use a URL there.

I don't know much about C++, but have a quick look at Mapnik's source code here:

In `map_parser::parse_point_symbolizer` (line 950 in [load_map.cpp](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/a077ccd4f6296643cfff2f726a6cabe7ac0a3024/src/load_map.cpp#L950)) the symbolizer file name is checked with `ensure_exists(filename)` (line 1661). That function calls `mapnik::util::exists`.

`mapnik::util::exists` then calls `boost::filesystem::exists` (lines 41ff in [fs.cpp](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/a077ccd4f6296643cfff2f726a6cabe7ac0a3024/src/fs.cpp#L41)).

The [Boost Filesystem documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) doesn't mention URLs or HTTP calls anywhere, it is used only for files and paths on the local file system.

I haven't looked at other parts of the code much, but at least in the part where the file path is checked, an URL would cause an error.